# Nested array of objects aggregation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Documents in the Elasticsearch are indexed as such

Document 1

```
{
  "task_completed": 10
  "tagged_object": [
    {
      "category": "cat",
      "count": 10
    },
    {
      "category": "cars",
      "count": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

Document 2

```
{
  "task_completed": 50
  "tagged_object": [
    {
      "category": "cars",
      "count": 100
    },
    {
      "category": "dog",
      "count": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see that the value of the category key is dynamic in nature. I want to perform a similar aggregation like in SQL with the group by category and return the sum of the count of each category.

In the above example, the aggregation should return
cat: 10,
cars: 120 and
dog: 5

Wanted to know how to write this aggregation query in Elasticsearch if it is possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve your required result, using [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html), [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html), and [sum](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) aggregation.

Adding a working example with index mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "tagged_object": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "resellers": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "tagged_object"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "books": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "tagged_object.category.keyword"
          },
          "aggs":{
            "sum_of_count":{
              "sum":{
                "field":"tagged_object.count"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "resellers": {
      "doc_count": 4,
      "books": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "cars",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "sum_of_count": {
              "value": 120.0
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "cat",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "sum_of_count": {
              "value": 10.0
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "dog",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "sum_of_count": {
              "value": 5.0
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @user2250206 please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?